# Add weekly tasks, monthly tasks in google spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, sum

I was tasked to add the total weekly tasks and monthly tasks.
So initially, my idea is just to do this.
`SUM(J1:J5)`
Since that would actually total the weekly tasks, however, if I drag that down to autofill the columns, it would result to:
`SUM(J2:J6)`
It just adds 1 to continue the order, what I want is this:
`SUM(J7:J12)`

Or, if there's any other way to do the adding up of weekly tasks and monthly tasks dynamically, please enlighten me.

Thank you.

Comment: Using [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) with [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316) could do that but the use of [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) should be smarter.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know the layout, data, data types, international locale or data-based end goal (i.e., we don't know what is in J2:J6, J7:J12, their relative significance to any data around them, etc.). Help us to help you by sharing a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).

Comment: Are you working in Googlesheet? If so, why did you tag Excel - they are different.

Comment: J1:J5 = 5 cells. the next one J7:J12 = 6 cells and J6 is skipped. whats next??? skip one or two? sum 5 next cells or 6 or 7?

Comment: @Erik Tyler, unfortunately, I cannot share it since it's a company file. The data type for J column which I indicated the cells is integer, they contain amount of work done by day i.e. J2 contains the work done by May 18, and the rest goes on. The two crucial columns in the spreadsheet is I (for dates) and then J(for work done under the indicated date)

Comment: @SolarMike, Yes I'm using Googlesheet, I actually tagged googlesheet. Most of excel's basic formulas work in Googlesheet.

Comment: @player0, no, I did solve it for the time being using IF, SUM and INDIRECT. It's like J2:J6 for five days, and what I wanted is after that, I'd go to J6:J10, another five days. Do you know how to set that?

Comment: But some don’t exist and others have the arguments in a different order… which is why we separate them.

Comment: Add a column to give the week number then use sumifs().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("J"&ROW(J1)*5+1-5&":J"&ROW(J1)*5))
```

[image]

Comment: you are an amazing human being! thank you.